# ig7icd32.pdb not loaded. Access Violation reading location

Tags: debugging

I get a really weird exception on Visual Studio 17 window saying "Exception thrown at 0x58ABCDF5 : Access violation reading location.".

This started happening after I updated my graphics card (Intel HD 4000):

[image: This is how it looks like.]

My System Specifications :

- Computer : Sony Corporation SVF1521C2EB
- Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (64-bit)
- Processor : Intel® Core™ i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz
- Graphics : Intel® HD Graphics 4000
- Memory : 4 GB

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a weird error. Your program is simply trying to dereference (`reading location`) a null pointer (`0x00000000`). The `.pdb` file that can not be loaded is a file that contains debug information for that particular DLL, which happend to be part of the Intel GPU drivers.

Most likely reason: You're trying to use some kind of Buffer Object, and called `glVertex…Pointer` with a null based offset (as you do for Buffer Objects), but without an actual Buffer Object being bound it the first place, when the actual access does happen (`glDraw…`).

Comment: fixed it! Thanks.

Comment: The problem was occuring here : if (_vboID = 0)
                                             glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);                                                                              I used = instead of == so it was pointing to nothing.                                                                It was a big facepalm for me. haha...

Comment: @TirthPatel: You're your own worst enemy… That being said, to disarm your enemy (= yourself) learn about [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) (i.e. placing const values on the left hand side of comparisions), and get into the habit of writing superfluously, because each character to type more is one you could mistype.

Comment: Oh! I never heard about it. It would surely help me. Thank you so much.